# How to get the status of stopped processes on using docker restart command

Tags: docker

When we restart a container using '`docker restart command`', docker first stops and then starts the container.
My question is when the container is stopped? I wanted to know the exit status of the container.

Answer (score 1):

i dont really get what you trying to say. .but if you wanna know the exit status, you can just issue 
`docker ps -a`
 command to list all exited container with their status code,

but if you want to check it with more specific condition, you can use something like :

`docker ps -a --filter 'exited=0'` that mean the container exited successfully,

or

`docker ps -a --filter 'exited=137'` 137 code meaning a SIGKILL(9) killed them.

[here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering)  s more about docker filtering reference

oh, try using some punctuation marks in your sentence next time

Comment: i will frame this question in other-way While using 'docker restart' command is there any way to know whether the container is exited gracefully or forcefully.

Comment: you can use this for more specific exited code `docker inspect 'container_id' --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'` and you can find the container id by listing all of docker container `docker ps -a` the exit status code is following the standard `chroot exit codes`

Answer (score 0):

EXIT status can be seen by using

> docker ps -a

And you can check docker logs.

> docker logs CONTAINER_NAME

for more information check - [Docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)